# Dynamically linked pages ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have created a Master page. And I have created a default page named default.aspx The defult aspx file has all of the standard content and ID's. In the ID I made a div tag to hold content for the dynamic page.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"         CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="P03_S02.Link1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div id="DynPage" runat="server"></div>
</asp:Content>
```

This is all good. So by using SQL server express that comes with Visual Studio 2012 I created a table with data in it. The entitys in the table is
    ProductID
    Name
    Price
    Quantity

Now in the default.aspx.vb page I completed the following code.

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Catelog
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        Dim Connection As SqlConnection
        Dim Command As SqlCommand
        Dim Reader As SqlDataReader
        Connection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Products.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
        Dim CommandString As String
        CommandString = "SELECT * FROM Product"
        Command = New SqlCommand(CommandString)
        Command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        Command.Connection = Connection
        Command.Connection.Open()
        Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Reader = Command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

        Dim ProductList As String
        If Reader.HasRows Then
            ProductList &= "<table width=""100%"">"
            ProductList &= " <tr bgcolor=""#00CCFF"">"
            ProductList &= "<td><b>ID</b></td>"
            ProductList &= "<td><b>Product</b></td>"
            ProductList &= "<td><b>Price</b></td>"
            ProductList &= "<td><b>Quantity</b></td>"
            ProductList &= "</tr>"
            While Reader.Read
                Dim newProduct As String
                ProductList &= "<tr>"
                ProductList &= "<td>" & Reader("ProductID") & "</td>" & _
                "<td>" & "<a href=""Link1.aspx?ProdID=""" & Reader("Name") & ">" &      Reader("Name") & "</a>" & "</td>" & _
                    "<td>" & Reader("Price") & "</td>" & _
                    "<td>" & Reader("Quantity") & "</td>"
                    ProductList &= "</tr>"
                End While
                ProductList &= "</table>"
            End If
            Catelog.InnerHtml = ProductList
            Command.Connection.Close()
       '    Command.Dispose()
            Connection.Dispose()
            ProductCatelog.InnerHtml = ProductList
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

As you can see the table will display all data form the table. In the while loop I make each name in the table hyperlinks to another apsx file named Link1.

I used the same code as above but changed a few things in Link1.aspx.vb

Added:

```
  Dim ProductID As String
  ProductID = Request.QueryString("ProdID").ToString()'problem possible here
```

Changed the Display of data:

```
     Dim ProductList As String
        If Reader.HasRows Then
            ProductList &= "<table width=""100%"">"
            ProductList &= " <tr bgcolor=""#00CCFF"">"
            ProductList &= "<td><b>Product</b></td>"
            ProductList &= "<td><b>Price</b></td>"
            ProductList &= "<td><b>Quantity</b></td>"
            ProductList &= "</tr>"
            While Reader.Read
                Dim newProduct As String
                ProductList &= "<tr>"
                ProductList &= "<td>" & Reader("Name") & "</td>" & _
                    "<td>" & Reader("Price") & "</td>" & _
                    "<td>" & Reader("Quantity") & "</td>"
                ProductList &= "</tr>"
            End While
            ProductList &= "</table>"
        End If
```

Used the following to display only one record:

```
        Dim CommandString As String
        CommandString = "SELECT * FROM Product where ProductID =" & ProductID
```

My goal is if you click on a name it will link it to Link1.aspx and display only information about that name (Info in table). That does not happen because the program crashes.  I have used all my basic debugging knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In default.aspx.vb you have :

```
"<td>" & "<a href=""Link1.aspx?ProdID=""" & Reader("Name") & ">" &      Reader("Name") & "</a>" & "</td>" & _
```

passing name as ProdID
for ProdID you are passing Name  and in link1.aspx.vb you are querying like:

```
Dim ProductID As String
ProductID = Request.QueryString("ProdID").ToString()'problem possible here
```

and later:

```
Dim CommandString As String
CommandString = "SELECT * FROM Product where ProductID =" & ProductID
```

expecting ProdID, not Name.

So, in default.aspx.vb you should change the line to:

```
<td>" & "<a href=""Link1.aspx?ProdID=""" & Reader("ProdID").ToString() & ">" &
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, look up SqlParameters, because you've just opened your code up to SQL injection by passing parameters in the QueryString.

To address your question, I think the problem lies with this line:

`"<td>" & "<a href=""Link1.aspx?ProdID=""" & Reader("Name") & ">" &      Reader("Name") & "</a>" & "</td>" & _`

You are closing your double-quote too soon and the productId isn't being put inside the href.

I'd rewrite it like this:

`"<td>" & "<a href=""Link1.aspx?ProdID=" & Reader("Name") & """>" &      Reader("Name") & "</a>" & "</td>" & _`

Subtle difference, but it should make it work.

Finally, always do a null/empty string check on the QueryString before you call `.ToString()`.  Compare your `QueryString` entry using `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`, and then only continue processing when `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` returns false.